# Having JavaScript if statement run periodically and not once without using setInterval

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently running an if statement looped by setInterval 100ms to add and remove classes when the browser is scrolled more than 450px. Obviously, not looping it makes it only run once which is not what I want. I've heard setInterval may lag the browser though, so is there a way to optimize this code better?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if(window.scrollY > 450) {
    document.querySelector('.whatever').classList.remove("whatever2);
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.whatever').classList.add("whatever3");
  }
}, 100);
```

The code works in this manner, but obviously I want it as optimized as possible. I used to use jQuery, and I was able to replicate this with document.ready as so:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(checkScroll);
    function checkScroll() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()>=450) {
            $('.whatever').addClass('whatever2');
        }else{
            $('.whatever').removeClass('whatever3');
        }
    }
});
```

I struggle converting it to JavaScript in a better manner though.

Comment: What's the problem? The `scroll` event isn't specific to jQuery. Just write a vanilla JavaScript event listener for `scroll`.

Comment: Do you mean scrolling to be at 450px, or is it a specific place within the page? I ask because of responsiveness, obviously 450px will work only for certain viewport dimension. If it's actually at a certain place within the page then IntersectionObserver would probably help and be a lot less overhead than having to check at set intervals.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the jQuery code to vanilla JS?

Comment: @Spectric that would be pretty ideal, I see how it works using the scroll listener as Barmar pointed out but for some reason, everytime I try re-creating it in vanilla javascript and fitting it into my current code something does not work, so I just gave up on that avenue.

Comment: Did you mean to remove the `whatever3` class or the `whatever2` class (in the `else` clause of the `if` statement)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll)
  function checkScroll() {
    if (window.scrollY >= 450) {
      document.querySelector('.whatever').classList.add('whatever2');
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.whatever').classList.remove('whatever3');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
html, body{
  height:200%;
}
.whatever{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.whatever2{
  background-color:red;
}
.whatever3{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="whatever whatever3">
Hello World!
</div>
```

Comment: it works perfectly, pretty strange that I did something similar and it didn't work, must have made a very small oversight on spelling maybe... Thank you